Pyomo ImportError: module ‘pyomo.common’ has no attribute ‘errors’
I’m working with Pyomo in a Python environment, and I’ve encountered an AttributeError when trying to import Pyomo modules. The error message states that the module ‘pyomo.common’ has no attribute ‘errors’. Here’s the code snippet that causes the error:
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

# Variables
model.x = Var(range(len(wh_capacities_df)), within=NonNegativeReals)

# Objective
model.obj = Objective(expr=sum((model.x[i] - demand_per_day[i])**2 for i in range(len(demand_per_day))), sense=minimize)

# Constraints
model.constraints = ConstraintList()
for i in range(len(wh_capacities_df)):
    model.constraints.add(model.x[i] <= wh_capacities_df['Daily Capacity '].iloc[i])

# Solve
SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model)

# Display results
for i in range(len(wh_capacities_df)):
    print(f"Optimal capacity for plant {wh_capacities_df['Plant ID'].iloc[i]}: {model.x[i].value}")


full error message
{
    "name": "AttributeError",
    "message": "module 'pyomo.common' has no attribute 'errors'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 1
----> 1 from pyomo.environ import *
      3 model = ConcreteModel()
      5 # Variables

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pyomo\\environ\\__init__.py:86
     82         pkg = _sys.modules[pname]
     83         pkg.load()
---> 86 _import_packages()
     88 #
     89 # Expose the symbols from pyomo.core
     90 #
     91 from pyomo.dataportal import DataPortal

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pyomo\\environ\\__init__.py:66, in _import_packages()
     64 pname = _package + '.plugins'
     65 try:
---> 66     _do_import(pname)
     67 except ImportError:
     68     exctype, err, tb = _sys.exc_info()  # BUG?

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pyomo\\environ\\__init__.py:18, in _do_import(pkg_name)
     17 def _do_import(pkg_name):
---> 18     importlib.import_module(pkg_name)

File C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py:90, in import_module(name, package)
     88             break
     89         level += 1
---> 90 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pyomo\\core\\__init__.py:83
     69 from pyomo.core.expr.symbol_map import SymbolMap
     70 from pyomo.core.expr import (
     71     numvalue,
     72     numeric_expr,
   (...)
     81     calculus,
     82 )
---> 83 from pyomo.core import expr, util, kernel
     85 from pyomo.core.expr.numvalue import (
     86     nonpyomo_leaf_types,
     87     PyomoObject,
   (...)
     96     ZeroConstant,
     97 )
     98 from pyomo.core.expr.boolean_value import (
     99     as_boolean,
    100     BooleanConstant,
    101     BooleanValue,
    102     native_logical_values,
    103 )

File pyomo\\\\core\\\\util.pyx:19, in init pyomo.core.util()

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pyomo\\core\\base\\__init__.py:38
     18 from pyomo.core.expr.numvalue import (
     19     nonpyomo_leaf_types,
     20     native_types,
   (...)
     29     ZeroConstant,
     30 )
     31 from pyomo.core.expr.boolean_value import (
     32     as_boolean,
     33     BooleanConstant,
     34     BooleanValue,
     35     native_logical_values,
     36 )
---> 38 from pyomo.core.base.component import name, Component, ModelComponentFactory
     39 from pyomo.core.base.componentuid import ComponentUID
     40 from pyomo.core.base.config import PyomoOptions

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\pyomo\\core\\base\\component.py:79
     74 @deprecated(msg=\"The cname() function has been renamed to name()\", version='5.6.9')
     75 def cname(*args, **kwds):
     76     return name(*args, **kwds)
---> 79 class CloneError(pyomo.common.errors.PyomoException):
     80     pass
     83 class ComponentBase(PyomoObject):

AttributeError: module 'pyomo.common' has no attribute 'errors'"
}

I’ve tried updating Pyomo and checking for any conflicts with other packages, but the issue persists. I’m using Python 3.12 and Pyomo version 6.7.3 and downgrade to Pyomo-5.7.3 also didnt worked. Has anyone else encountered this issue, or does anyone know how to resolve it?

You are probably using the wrong import statement. Looking at the docs,
The class SolverFactory is imported from pyomo.opt but you seem to want to access it via your wildcard import from pyomo.environ import *. Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. See Imports.
Your import statements should look like this:
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

Then you can do:
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
...

See Working with Pyomo Models.
